# String to Blob and Blob to String conversion during encryption/decryption

Tags: encryption, blob

I'm getting the error when I'm trying to decrypt an encrypted value in line 7.

```
Blob exampleIv = Blob.valueOf('Example of IV123');
Blob key = Crypto.generateAesKey(128);
Blob data = Blob.valueOf(randStr);
Blob encrypted = Crypto.encrypt('AES128', key, exampleIv, data);
Con.Password__c = String.valueOf(encrypted);

Blob Passwrd = Blob.valueOf(Con.Password__c);
        
Blob decrypted = Crypto.decrypt('AES128', key, exampleIv, Passwrd);
String decryptedString = decrypted.toString();
```

Can someone suggest how I convert string to Blob?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.valueOf` accept `Blob` as input considering it as an `Object` and I'm not sure which encoding type is used during the conversion of blob to string. On the other hand, I guess `Blob.valueOf` expects an UTF-8 encoded string. *Getting into the details of this is probably beyond the scope of this question.*

So in your code, the conversion of blob - string - blob is possibly losing some bytes of data required by the `Crypto.decrypt` method, there by leading to `System.SecurityException`. Consider using `EncodingUtil` methods for conversion of string to blob and vice-versa (using `base64`).

You will have to replace

```
Con.Password__c = String.valueOf(encrypted);
Blob Passwrd = Blob.valueOf(Con.Password__c);
```

with

```
Con.Password__c = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(encrypted);
Blob Passwrd = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(Con.Password__c);
```

Comment: thank you, it works.